# How to Achive this UI Screenshort UI? with dots indicator in Xamarin forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

[image]

I have confussion to achive this dots layout with differnt pages thats bind with the viewpager in Xamarin Forms.I want to achive this ui in Xamarin forms.

Comment: Any link for this page? What Nuget did you use? Are you confused about how to put three views together with an indicator, what about your code?

Comment: No its Just Design @Shaw .I think this is carsol view with contentview

Comment: Have you tried [indicatorview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/indicatorview), if you are in favour of carousel?